# Linux commands - piping commands

Tags: linux, shell, command, piping

I tried the following command `find ~/dir1 *.m4a | play`

Directory dir1 has exactly 1 m4a file in it and I'd like it to be played
Yet I get a usage error from play. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that `play` accepts files from its STDIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be play don't use STDIN so you have to use xargs

```
 find ~/dir1 \*.m4a |xargs play
```

Comment: You got lucky that the current directory didn't also contain a.m4a file, in which case your original answer would not work.  You MUST escape shell metacharacters in patterns for `find`.  I have updated your answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote instructs the output of the find command (an m4a file) to be send over *as the input* to the next command, play.

Now, I have no idea what that play exactly is, but most likely, it's syntax is of the type:

```
play filename
```

But what you wrote translates to:

```
play < "filename"
```

So, what you probably want to do is use a command like xargs, which will do exactly that:

```
find ~/dir1 *.m4a | xargs play
```

Which results in:

```
play foundfile1 foundfile2 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pipe the contents of the file into play (i.e. sending it in via STDIN). As far as I can see from the play man page, it can't do this.

You want to send the filename that find to play, like this:

find ~/dir1 *.m4a | xargs play

Answer (score 1):

Use `find -name *.mp4 -exec play {} /;`

Answer (score -1):

Try the other way:

```
play ~/dir1 *.m4a
```

If not working - check if play support m4a

or try with xargs in your pip line

```
xargs play
```